# Parse.com array of files

Tags: arrays, file, parse-platform

I am uploading images to Parse.com and in a successful response it returns the filename (generated) and the file URL. It this is fine for single association however one of my classes needs to have many files to one entry.

Currently trying to make an array of `Pointers` / `File` references so it they show in the data browser as blue buttons. The problem is that it does not create these blue buttons it just throws the object into the array as it is.

```
    $scope.saveCreatedExercise = function(exercise) {
        imageStore = []
        for (var i = 0; i < exercise.images.length; i++) {

            var data = {
                "__type": "File",
                "name": exercise.images[i]._name
            }
            imageStore.push(data);
        };

        ParseFactory.provider('ClientExercises/').create({
            exerciseDescription: exercise.exerciseDescription,
            exerciseName: exercise.exerciseName,
            user: {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "_User",
                "objectId": Parse.User.current().id
            },
            images: imageStore

        }).success(function(data) {
            $state.go('app.exercises', {
                loadProgramme: data.objectId
            });
        }).error(function(response) {
            errorFactory.checkError(response);
        });

    }
```

Is this even possible to achieve?

The crux of my problem is that I want one entry in my class to be associated to many files.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a working solution in case anyone else comes across this issue. The importance of this approach is that without saving the actual parse file object reference, when you use the settings to do a file clean-up, all of your referenced files will be deleted. This method keeps these files from being purged

I'm using angularjs and the parse javascript sdk in my implementation. The issue that I was having was a javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" at the moment of adding the ParseFile object to the parent object array field.

Angular v1.4.4, Parse JS v1.5

```
var parseObject = {{ existing parse object }}
var files = {{ existing array of files base64 encoded }}
var parseFiles = [];
var promises = [];

// loop through the files so first save them to parse cloud 
// (in my case these files were uploaded via ng-file-upload)
angular.forEach(files, function(file,i){
  parseFiles[i] = new Parse.File(file.name,{
    base64: file.dataUrl
  });
  promises.push(parseFiles[i].save());
});

// actually save the files in one batch process of promises
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){
  // success callback says all files are saved, now lets add them to the parent
  angular.forEach(parseFiles, function(parseFile,i){
    delete parseFile._previousSave; //--> fix circular json error
    parseObject.addUnique('images',parseFile); // could alternatively use .add()
  });
  // now save the parent with the references to the files
  return parseListing.save();
}).then(function(){
  successCallback();
},function(error) {
  errorCallback();
});
```